# C# função Lambda com multiplas validações, verificação usando contains com multiplas comparações

Tags: c#, lista, validação, expressões-lambda, contains

- **_lancamento** é uma List com diversos registros
- **x.localizado** é um bool
- **x.descricao** é uma string

Estou tentando da seguinte forma

`if (_lancamento.Where(x => x.Localizado && x.descricao.Contains(new List<string> { "6", "9" }))){....}`

não sei se é possível fazer uma validação desta forma, tentei de varias formas em lambda e não consegui fazer funcionar. Obvio que o retorno que eu quero desse if é um True ou False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tenta essa solução ae, compara

```
_lancamento.Where(x => x.Localizado && new List<string> { "6", "9" }.Contains(String.Join("", Regex.Split(x.descricao, @"[^\d]")))
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, valeu